# Retrieve the authority on past commits after configurating Git Bash

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-config

I was committing a lot of changes to repo in GitHub. But when I looked to **Contributors** tab - I didn't see that they were registered.

I've taken a look on *my* commits - they had default GitHub photo and username, which isn't referencing to my profile (!).

After configuring bash again my further changes are logged, it's good, but..
But is there any change to make all of my previous commits be actually **mine**? If yes - how?

It would be awesome to show that I did my part of the work, without pointing on closed PR's with my changes, which *do* belong to me, but **aren't** registered like so.

Answer (score 0):

[Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/) — because the commits use email that isn't registered in your profile.

To assign the commits back to you either add the email to your Github profile or [rewrite commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750182/7976758) to change author/committer email.